# pasted piece of code on Xcode and got an error>>Execution was interrupted

Tags: xcode, swift

I pasted a code from swift programming language pdf by Apple from Methods chapter and got an error saying: Execution was interrupted reason,EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_1386_GPFLT).

The Error happens in the fourth line
 I don't know what does it mean and how to solve it
The code:

```
struct LevelTracker {
static var highestUnlockedLevel = 1
static func unlockLevel(level: Int) {
    if level > highestUnlockedLevel { highestUnlockedLevel = level } 
 (Error happens here)
}
static func levelIsUnlocked(level: Int) -> Bool {
    return level <= highestUnlockedLevel
}
var currentLevel = 1
mutating func advanceToLevel(level: Int) -> Bool {
    if LevelTracker.levelIsUnlocked(level) {
        currentLevel = level
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
}

class Player {
var tracker = LevelTracker()
let playerName: String
func completedLevel(level: Int) {
    LevelTracker.unlockLevel(level + 1)
    tracker.advanceToLevel(level + 1)
}
init(name: String) {
    playerName = name
}
}
var player = Player(name: "Argyrios")
player.completedLevel(1)
println("highest unlocked level is now \(LevelTracker.highestUnlockedLevel)")
```

Comment: Open the console (press Cmd+Shift+Y if you don't see the console on the bottom of Xcode) and you'll be able to see a more detailed error, which you can post here for more help.

Comment: it shows nothing @DPlusV

Comment: @user3783574 please fix formatting in your post. It's really hard to read this code with indentation broken.